# waitForSelectors not selecting element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to log into my Verizon account with the following CasperJS script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts:["/Developer/CasperJS/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"],
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug",
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false
    }
});

//get pwd and id from command line
var utils = require('utils');
var id = casper.cli.raw.get('id');
var pwd = casper.cli.raw.get('pwd');
var challenge = casper.cli.raw.get('challenge');


casper.start("https://login.verizonwireless.com/amserver/UI/Login", function(){
    console.log("Verizon site opened");
});

casper.then(function(){
    console.log("Login");
    casper.waitForSelector("form#login-form", function (){
        this.fillSelectors('form#login-form', {
            'input[id=IDToken1]': id
        }, true);
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
    console.log("Challenge");
    casper.waitForSelector("#challengequestion", function(){
        this.fillSelectors('form#challengequestion', {
            'input[id=IDToken1]': challenge
        }, false);
    });
});


casper.then(function(){
    console.log("taking screenshot");
    this.capture('login.png');
})

casper.run();
```

When I run that script all of the steps up to the Challenge portion complete. I verified that I was using the correct selector. Here is the relevant form from the Verizon page:

```
<form id="challengequestion" name="challengequestion" method="post" action="https://login.verizonwireless.com:443/amserver/UI/Login">
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="goto" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="5555555555">

    <input type="hidden" name="displayLoginStart" value="true">
    <input id="IDToken1" type="password" value="" autocomplete="off" name="IDToken1" tabindex="1" class="same-line">

    <p><a class="o-link-strong" href="https://login.verizonwireless.com/accessmanager/public/c/fp/start?fa=true" onclick="forgotMyAnswerClicked();" target="_top">Forgot your answer?</a></p>


    <div id="remember-me-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberComputer" id="rememberComputer" tabindex="2" value="Y" checked="checked"><label for="rememberComputer">Register this device</label>
        <span class="o-icon-question" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" tabindex="0" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="&quot;Register this device&quot; stores information on your device so we know you are a My Verizon registered customer. You should not use this feature on public devices (such as those in a public library).">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="rememberComputerCheckBoxExists" value="Y">



    <button id="continueButton" class="o-red-button same-line" type="submit" onclick="continueClicked();">Continue</button>


    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="o">

</fieldset>
</form>
```

And finally the output:

```
Challenge
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/7: done in 2791ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/8 https://login.verizonwireless.com/amserver/UI/Login (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/8: done in 2812ms.
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a `this.wait(5000, function(){this.capture("challenge.png")})` before the failing `waitForSelector` to see if you're even on the correct page.

Comment: I added the code and it does appear to be on the right page. Not sure what is going on...

Comment: Do you see the element you're trying to wait in the screenshot? Is the selector you're trying to wait in an iframe?

Comment: The element that I'm trying to wait is indeed in the screenshot. I don't know if this will help, but here is the generated png: http://imgur.com/L5qplBm  The generated png shows the form that I have in markup in the op.

Comment: You haven't answered my second question. Also, have you printed the page source with `this.echo(this.getHTML())`? to see if the element is actually there? Some sites will deliver different markup depending on the browser and viewport. PhantomJS has a default size of 400x300 which is far smaller than the normal desktop browser size.

Comment: It was in an iframe. I used withFrame, and now it appears to be working. Thanks! If you'd like to add the iframe bit as an answer, I'll select it. Thanks for working with me on this!